# How to check if at least one attachment of multiple attachments is not .pdf?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've written a script for Outlook to move email, depending on the attachments.

The script is a part of a rule which checks all arriving emails.

If a mail has no attachments, or attachment is a file different from .pdf (.zip, .jpg or whatever), it goes to Error folder.

If an email has the .pdf file attached, it stays in Inbox.

Everything is working except if mail has two attachments - one .pdf file and one .zip file.
- If .zip file is the first attachment, mail goes to Error folder as it should.
- If .pdf file is the first attachment, it stays in Inbox but it should go to Error folder too.

I've tried to modify the loop and if, but outcome is always the same. I tried to use "Continue For" or "Continue Loop".

```
Sub PDF(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments
        If Not Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) = ".pdf" Then
            Item.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Error")
        End If
        Exit For
    Next
    Set myAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

I expect emails with at least one attachment different from .pdf to be sent to Error folder. Only emails with .pdf attachments should stay in Inbox.

Is there a way to move the mail if at least one of them is not .pdf? I don't understand why it checks the first attachment only.

**SOLUTION**

```
Sub PDF2(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim allPdf As Boolean
    allPdf = True

    For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments
        Debug.Print myAtt.DisplayName
        If Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) <> ".pdf" Then
            allPdf = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If allPdf = False Or Item.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
        Item.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Error")
    End If

    Set myAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Still have to add recognition between hidden attachments and normal ones, but this script also moves mail without any attachments to Error folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Exit For was in Wrong Line**

**Try:**

```
Sub PDF(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments
        If Not Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) = ".pdf" Then
               Item.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Error")
               Exit For
        End If

    Next
    Set myAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

**New Edited Code:**

```
Sub PDF(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments
        Debug.Print myAtt.DisplayName
        If Not Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) = ".pdf" And Not Left(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) = "imag" Then
              Item.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Error")
              Exit For
        End If

    Next
    Set myAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

See this one is not perfect, but will make you understand what I mean. usually images are starting by imag, so we will skip those files as well.

Comment: I tried this earlier, but when I write "Exit For" before "End If", the script moves all emails to the Error folder, even those with .pdf attachment. When I remove "Exit For", or write it after "End If", it works as described in a question, but not with multiple attachments.

Comment: @Perceptio , that's happening because every mail have attachments other than PDF, most of them have images in jpg etc, which are not visible in the Attachments but are present in the Mail. if you can make up a list of which files you want to move other than PDF, then you can work up a code.

Comment: @Perceptio , Try the Edited New Code

Comment: the problem is I have no idea what are the files other than PDF that could be present in the mail. It can be everything, .xml, .doc, .png

Comment: unfortunatley it's not solving my problem. I've written a code that is ignoring some file formats, but I can't write all of them. And the problem is that it ALWAYS checks only the first attachment! Something is wrong with the loop, it should go through all attachments.

Comment: Yes, Your Loop have a problem that i fixed in the Answer. But for your problem I have already explained that there are other files in a Mail, just not what we look in the attachments. So if you loop through all of the, most probably you will find images other than PDF, so your code will move all of the mails. i don't think that's hard to understand. The only workaround to that I have answered in the Edited Code. that should solve your problem.

Comment: Oh my God yes, I finally understand. It was all because of the Organisation image in the text of the email. Is it possible to make the script distinguish attachments in the text from those added to the mail, "outside" of the text? Adding the rule to accept graphic files solved it, but I would like not to accept the graphic files added to mail, only the ones which are inside the text.

Comment: You should ask a new question now. I ll appreciate if you can accept the answer as well, it will help people looking for answers in Future. All the best with your code :)

Comment: I have found another problem. If there are no attachments in email, it should go to Error folder too, but it stays in inbox. So with the current script only emails with no attachments or only PDF attachments stay in inbox and this is wrong. I am trying to solve this problem with some boolean, but I am missing something. Is there a way in VGA to check if MailItem.Attachments is empty?

Comment: Nevermind, I created allPdf boolean and made it True. Now if script finds an attachment which is not pdf, it changes it to False. Second If moves mail to folder if one of two requirements is met - allPdf is False or Mailitem.Attachments.Count = 0. And it works :) I will update the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Exit For` is just one line to late.

It probably should looks like

```vb
   If Not Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) = ".pdf" Then
       Item.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Error")
       Exit For
   End If
```

Comment: As I've written in an answer to Mikku answer, I tried this, but it then moves all emails to the Error folder, even those with .pdf attachments.

Comment: Sorry for the carelessness. I only addressed the "it checks only the first attachment" aspect. @Mikku seems to be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

> if .zip file is the first attachment, mail goes to the Error folder (as it should be).

Basically, you don't need to check attachments, it seems you are interested in the first item only. Anyway, the code checks every attachment:

```
Sub PDF(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    For Each myAtt In Item.Attachments        
        If Not Right(LCase(myAtt.FileName), 4) = ".pdf" Then
            Item.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Error")
            Return 
        End If 
    Next
    Set myAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm interested in all attachments, because if at least one of them is not .pdf, mail should go to the Error folder. Attachments could be added in different order to the email and checking the first one is not the best option. Sometimes the second one could be a .zip file. I guess I probably didn't write it correctly - sorry for that. I already edited it.